# Google Drive files list, md5Checksum and headRevisionId

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm interacting with the Google Drive API (in Python) and I'm facing the following situation:

I'm using `service.files().list()` to get a list of files. Among the files listed I'm getting back the follwing file (real ids redacted):

`{
  'id': '<fileid>',
  'name': 'foo.zip',
  'version': '4', 
  'modifiedTime': '2016-08-08T12:00:00.000Z',
  'md5Checksum': 'c21ca263ad0e124511a36e3260ffdf35', 
  'size': '4816548',
  'headRevisionId': '<revisionId1>'
}`

And here is the result of `service.revisions().list(fileId='<fileid>')`:

`[
  {
    'id': '<revisionId1>',
    'modifiedTime': '2016-08-08T12:00:00.000Z',
    'originalFilename': 'foo.zip',
    'md5Checksum': '5a7e2a53f274e1dc8838a4d6a440f808'
  },
  {
    'id': '<revisionId2>',
    'modifiedTime': '2016-08-08T12:00:00.000Z',
    'originalFilename': 'foo.zip',
    'md5Checksum': 'c21ca263ad0e124511a36e3260ffdf35'
  } 
]`

I'm confused by the "inversion" in the reported `md5Checksum` and `headRevisionId` for this file.

From there, I'm asking myself the following questions:

- when using `files().list()`, is the reported `md5Checksum` the checksum of the alongside `headRevisionId`? I would assume it is since imho `files().list()` can't list anything but files in their most recent revision
- is the list returned by `revisions().list()` ordered and can I assume the last element of the list/array is the head revision?
- do you consider, just like I'm doing, that there's something bogus and can you imagine how you can end up is such a situation?

Thank you

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? In your question, ``service.revisions().get()`` is ``service.revisions().list()``? And although all ``modifiedTime`` are the same, can I think that the actual values are different?

Comment: In my environment (Drive API v3), I could confirm that when ``headRevisionId`` and ``md5Checksum`` are retrieved by ``drive.files.get`` and ``drive.files.list``, they coincide with the latest ``id`` and ``md5Checksum`` which were retrieved by "drive.revisions.list". And I can also confirm it by ``drive.revisions.get`` using ``fileId`` and ``headRevisionId``. So, for example, if you try this situation to the different file (text/plain), will your situation be able to be replicated?

Comment: @Tanaike thanks for commenting. Indeed it's `service.revisions().list()` I'm sorry for the typo. `modifiedTime` are really the same as reported by the API. It's not a copy paste error so I can't use them to infer what revision is the latest.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, I could understand that all ``modifiedTime`` of revision list are the same. This is an interesting situation. Unfortunately, I couldn't replicate your situation. In my environment, all ``modifiedTime`` are different. So can you confirm the following test?

Comment: For example, at first, it creates a text file on Google Drive. When it manually updates several times, I think that all ``modifiedTime`` of revision list will be different. At that time, from ``headRevisionId`` and ``md5Checksum``, can you confirm whether the situation is the same with your issue? If the correct revision ID can be obtained, I think that the same ``modifiedTime`` might be the reason of the issue.

Comment: There is a latency before some file metadata is updated. Have you tried the test several minutes later?

Comment: The files have been untouched for a while. They live in the accounts of users of my app. I think it's really Google Drive keeping a broken state

Comment: I'm really sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: That's ok @Tanaike ❤️ Maybe someone from google will chime in, they say they monitor questions tagged with #google-drive-sdk ‍♂️

Comment: @Gregory Pakosz I hope that this is modified. Thank you, too.